# android java create linear layout inside gridlayout programatically

Tags: java, android, cardview

i'm trying to create cardview or linearlayout inside a gridlayout from API, so i try create it using java rather than xml,

i barely managed to achive what i want, but when the text view inside the layout is too long , the layout is broken,

here is the screenshoot when the text is short

[image]

and here it is when the text is too long

[image]

and here is my code

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout
    .LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
grid = v.findViewById(R.id.div_kategori);
grid.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
//grid.setLayoutParams(params);
grid.setColumnCount(3);
//grid.setRowCount(5);

int row = 1;
int col = 1;

for (int i=0; i<user.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = user.getJSONObject(i);
    String nama_kategori = obj.getString("nama_kategori");

    if(i>0){
        if(i%3==0){
            row++;
            col = 1;
        }
    }

    Log.d("nama_kategori",nama_kategori+" baris : "+row+" kolom : "+col);

    LinearLayout card = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout
        .LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),      GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f));
    card.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    card.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    card.setLayoutParams(param);

    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramframe = new LinearLayout
        .LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    frame.setLayoutParams(paramframe);
    frame.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.card_edge) );

    LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramlin = new LinearLayout
        .LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    paramlin.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    lin.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    lin.setLayoutParams(paramlin);
    lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
    tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    tv.setText("sssssssssss sssss ssssss sssssss");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(getContext());
    tv2.setText("dua dua dua dua dua dua ");
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv2.setMaxWidth(card.getWidth());

    lin.addView(tv);
    //lin.addView(tv2);
    frame.addView(lin);
    card.addView(frame);

    grid.addView(card);
    col++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to obtain, the problem should be that textviews are not limited in width.
Try setting ems and enabling horizontal scroll.. something like:

```
tv.setEms(10);
tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

Comment: thanks, but its not working, the result still the same

Answer (score 0):

To achieve layout like you want, 
You can use GridLayoutManager inside Recyclerview .

Below is link of that
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager

And below is example of same 
https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example

Answer (score 0):

finally i can achive it using this

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams param= new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(
                            GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f),
                            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f));
                    param.height = 0;
                    param.width = 0;
                    LinearLayout card = new LinearLayout(getContext());
```